# Mac 10.9.4 Python ImageTK module import not working "no module named ImageTK"

Tags: python-3.x, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to make a GUI on my mac (version 10.9.4) and I can't import the ImageTK module. I've installed python 3.4.1 and ActiveTCL 8.6.1 (the only edition available to the public) but I can't get the import to work. I've tried reinstalling python but that didn't help either.

When I use `from PIL import ImageTK` I get `name ImageTK is not defined` and when I try `import ImageTK` I get `No module named ImageTK`

Am I miss something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It have to be small `k` in place of big `K`

```
from PIL import ImageTk
```